# When I play Lord of Tresserhorn, can I sacrifice Doomed Dissenter and its Zombie token?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have a [Doomed Dissenter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Doomed%20Dissenter) on the battlefield.

> When Doomed Dissenter dies, create a 2/2 black Zombie creature token.

Then I play [Lord of Tresserhorn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lord%20of%20Tresserhorn).

> When Lord of Tresserhorn enters the battlefield, you lose 2 life, you sacrifice two creatures, and target opponent draws two cards.

For the two creatures I must sacrifice, can I choose Doomed Dissenter, and then the Zombie token it creates? Do I need to choose two creatures that are on the battlefield before either one dies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I sacrifice a creature for a spell and it creates a token, can I sacrifice that token for the spell too?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/24670/if-i-sacrifice-a-creature-for-a-spell-and-it-creates-a-token-can-i-sacrifice-th)

Comment: @Soulis not an exact duplicate (this is effect, that is cost) but the parts important to the question are the same. Close enough to close.

Answer (score 13):

No, you cannot.

The token is not created immediately; the triggered ability has to go on the stack and then resolve first. And it isn’t even placed on the stack until after you finish resolving the Tresserhorn enter-the-battlefield ability.

> 603. Handling Triggered Abilities
>
> > 603.2. Whenever a game event or game state matches a triggered ability’s trigger event, that ability automatically triggers. **The ability doesn’t do anything at this point.**
> >
> > 603.3. Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority.

So the 2/2 black Zombie creature token is not created until well after both the creatures have been sacrificed for Lord of Tresserhorn.